# Unable to create a new account on NEAR Protocol testnet

Tags: nearprotocol

I get to this page from  and I enter the correct code but nothing happens when I click **Verify & Continue**.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfZGd.png)

Comment: It was a temporary bug, and it would better to be posted in Discord or TG group. Should be resolved already.

Comment: It is resolved! Thanks!